# Serving content with both CORS and JSONP

Tags: php, ajax, api, jsonp, cors

I'm serving content for public websites and I'm wondering whether there would be any implications on using both CORS and JSONP for maximum browser support. For instance, I would be doing this:

```
<?php

// Simplified example to illustrate

if(isset($_GET['callback'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode( ... ) . ')';
    exit;
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode( ... );
```

Obviously I'm not sending the CORS-related headers with the JSONP response as that seems counter-intuitive. Are there any security or other implications with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `CORS` is here to stay, I'd propose switching the order in which you are sending out data.

1. [Detect CORS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)
2. If CORS is supported, send your `application/json` response
3. If CORS is not supported, fallback to `JSONP` (IE<=7, Opera<12, or Firefox<3.5)

This way you get to redeem the best of the more secure method and fall back to the other for non-compliant clients.